# Get a value from an input field

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using the code below using jQuery and AJAX, to update my database.

Deletion works perfectly, but the edit function is not working. How is it possible to get the value from each input field?

```
<ol class="update">
<?php

$ss = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM users_channels WHERE u_id='$uid'");
while ($chann = mysql_fetch_assoc($ss)) {
    echo'               
    <li>
    <input name="channelName" type="text" id="channelName" style="float:left; width:300px; border:1px solid #CCC;" value="'.$chann['channel_name'].'" />
    <a href="#" id="'.$chann['id'].'" class="delete_button"><span id="rcolor">Delete</span></a>
    <a href="#" id="'.$chann['id'].'" cvalue="'.$chann['channel_name'].'" class="save_button"><span id="gcolor">Save</span></a>
    </li>';
}

?>
</ol>
```

Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(function() {
        $(".save_button").click(function() {
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            var cvalue = $(this).attr("cvalue");
            var dataStringe = 'id=' + id + '&cvalue=' + cvalue;
            var parent = $(this).parent();

            alert(cvalue);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "update_channel.php",
                data: dataStringe,
                cache: false,

                beforeSend: function() {
                    parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'}, 300).animate({ opacity: 0.35 }, "slow");
                }, 
                success: function() {
                    //parent.slideUp('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: can u be more explicit? What do you need to get? Value of all input elements? if yes .. use $('input[name=example]').each(){}

Comment: $("#channelName").val()

Comment: i thing that's wrong because that input it's in a while so there are many inputs with that id, best will be a each()

Comment: i need when i am pressing save to get the value from the specific input field that has the save button next to it..

Also as you can see i am sending the values from <a href=""></a> But first i am grabbing the value for each input from my database

Comment: does that specific input field have any id or class?

Comment: yes.. but i am using it to grab the revord is to send it through ajax to update the record and a class name save_button to call the function..

Comment: ok if you've given class name to that input field you can get its value like this
`var value=$(".classname").val();`

if you've given id then you can get its value like this
`var value=$("#id").val();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in your java script function

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
    $(".save_button").click(function() {

        var inputVal=$("#channelName").val();

        //rest of your code

         return false;
        });
       });
     });
```

you'll get the value of an input field(as per your question) in *inputVal* variable.

In order to get the values of all input fields,give them a common class name instead of giving style there like this

```
<input class="myInput" type="text" value="red" id="one"/>
<input class="myInput" type="text" value="France" id="two" />
```

and then in your javascript add this

```
var inputValues= {};
$(".myInput").each(function() {
    inputValues[$(this).attr("id")] = $(this).val();
});

alert(inputValues.one); // "red"
```

you'll get the value of all input fields in *inputValues* variable

Comment: your question says "Get a value from an input field?"

so gave you the ans according to 1 input field.

Comment: changed the ans as you need it,try it and let me know

Comment: Your code works great my friend.. I want to appologie that i didnt give you the correct Title to my post..

each a href that i am using has a new custom attribute (cvalue) and this value i am passing through ajax. So when i am press the save button my code must grab the value from the field that has next to it the save button and append this value to the new cvalue attribute that i have add to the a href so it can be send the new value to php file and update the db.

Comment: Ok i don't know much of php however i know java script,if i answered your question and if it solved your problem,can you tick it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

can u be more explicit? What do you need to get? Value of all input elements? if yes .. use `$('input[name=example]').each(function(){})`
this will get all values of all input with specified name

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you're trying to do is submit the value of your input field as `cvalue`? To do this, the best approach would be:

```
$(".save_button").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  var parent = $(this).parent();
  var cvalue = parent.find('input').val(); // this gets the value of the <input> field
  var dataStringe = 'id='+ id + '&cvalue='+ cvalue;

  // the rest of your code...
});
```